# how to use helm-do-grep to search within subdirectories?

Tags: helm, rgrep

I am running the command `helm-do-grep` and I notice that the search is not recursive, i.e. it searches only in the directory I specify and not in subdirectories. How do I direct `helm-grep` to automatically search recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helm` does offer a non-recursive and a recursive command, by default it's using the non-recursive one when invoking `M-x helm-do-grep` unless it has been called with a prefix argument.  The values for the non-recursive and recursive command are stored in the `helm-grep-default-command` and `helm-grep-default-recurse-command` variables.

The easiest way of achieving recursion by default would be setting the former variable to the value of the latter.

```
(eval-after-load 'helm-grep
  '(setq helm-grep-default-command helm-grep-default-recurse-command))
```

Caution: The solution above might have unintended consequences, such as using `grep` on the buffers list to recurse on every listed file.

Comment: What's helm's recursive command? (I see helm-do-zgrep...) Would calling helm's recursive command be a safer way to invoke grep recursively than the above?

Comment: You can inspect it with `F1 v helm-grep-default-recurse-command`.

Comment: I get `grep -a -d recurse %e -n%cH -e %p %f`. What's the correct string for recursive searching?

Comment: Well, you set `helm-grep-default-command` to this value by `(setq helm-grep-default-command "grep -a -d recurse %e -n%cH -e %p %f")`.

Comment: But what's the new value for recursive search?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just leave it that way.

Comment: Evaluating the code in the answer makes it so that `helm-do-grep` doesn't run a search at all.

Comment: I find that hard to believe as I cannot reproduce that with a recent installation of `helm` and `emacs -Q`.